# Create EditText in Gridlayout programmatically in Android

Tags: android

I want to create editText everytime I clicked the button (create). and Set the id, column and row.

**Gridlayout id: inputTasksLayout
button id: addnewTask**

When i clicked the button, it will create an editText in column 1, row 1 and assigned an id (task1).

When i clicked the button again, it will create another editText in column 1, row 2 and assigned an id (task2).

When i clicked the button again, it will create another editText in column 1, row 2 and assigned an id (task3). And so on..

I want to know if its possible. If yes, can you give some sample codes? I tried the other sources but they are all in LinearLayout. I want to put it in GridLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes can EditText View Dynamically on the click of Button Here below is the sample code.

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputTasksLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="10">


</GridLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addnewTask"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="addView"
    android:text="Add" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int rowIndex = 1;
int colIndex = 0;
private GridLayout gridLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inputTasksLayout);
    gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

}

public void addView(View view) {
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    param.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    param.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(rowIndex);
    param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(colIndex);
    editText.setLayoutParams(param);
    if (rowIndex == 1) {
        editText.setId(R.id.task1);
    }
    if (rowIndex == 2) {
        editText.setId(R.id.task2);
    }

    gridLayout.addView(editText);
    rowIndex++;
 }
}
```

ids.xml in values folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<item name="task1" type="id" />
<item name="task2" type="id" />
<item name="task3" type="id" />
</resources>
```

Comment: omg thank you so much. T__T *tears of joy* this i understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course it is possible. It is one of two main ways to create Views. The good old code way...I prefer it over xml btw. but thats just me. I do nearly 90% of View creation and layouting in Code because I dont like the "dp" kind of way to say how wide or high a view ist for example....

You just create a new EditText via

```
new EditText();
```

Then you give it a height and a width.
Check for the methods you can use here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html
(EditText inherits the TextView)

And for your purpose check the Documentation of GridView out:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

most importantly :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews

the last link shows you how to insert an item into a layout like grid view for example.

It is as easy as XML but just needs a little bit more code.....

EDIT:
As you keep on persist on a code solution keep in mind that stack overflow is not for demanding a code solution in your questions. It is a plattform to get help not to receive specific solutions in code.

Check the opening text of my link:

"A layout defines the visual structure for a user interface, such as the UI for an activity or app widget. You can declare a layout in two ways:

Declare UI elements in XML. Android provides a straightforward XML vocabulary that corresponds to the View classes and subclasses, such as those for widgets and layouts.
Instantiate layout elements at runtime. Your application can create View and ViewGroup objects (and manipulate their properties) programmatically.
The Android framework gives you the flexibility to use either or both of these methods for declaring and managing your application's UI. For example, you could declare your application's default layouts in XML, including the screen elements that will appear in them and their properties. You could then add code in your application that would modify the state of the screen objects, including those declared in XML, at run time."

So if you read the text you can adapt the things you will learn not only for edittext but for all views and its subclasses its not that hard....

Again SO is not for demanding explicit code solutions

Comment: i don't understand the links u gave to me. a sample code will do

Comment: Sorry but Im not doing your work. The links I gave you is the standard documentation for Android and is very easy to read. I wont give you a copy -paste code. What would you learn out of it? Exactly 0!

Comment: All I can say is: Create your Edittext dynamically. Set their parameters as you like(widht, height etc), Grab a reference for your Layout and use an Adapter to fill the desiored Items into your layout(check out last link for that)

Comment: the documentation has many sample codes....you just need to anticipate them for your specific problem. That all I will help, wish you good luck

Comment: I actually prefer analyzing codes than reading notes. Cause that i would try the trial and error thing and then i will analyze how that code works. I learned a lot from it than what you think. The last link does have sample codes but i don't understand it. (-___-)

Comment: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-programmatically-generate.html SAMPLE CODES like this but in GridLayout . thats what im asking for....

Comment: I hope somebody takes the time to write just for you a code how to create a edittext, an adapter, buttons etc and then the logic for how to listen to the click events and dynamically fill in the edittext into your gridlayout using the adapter... As long as this dont happen you could read a bit and understand how to work with androids API properly. There wont be someone who gives you a code everytime you want a feature. Start to understand written language and try to anticipate. Its more efficient to read the docs then analyze the code...

Comment: also why use an adpater and gridlayout and edittext if you dont understand hwo they work.....again remember: if you want to fill edittexts into your gridlayout you need to use an adapter for that the rest is simple

Comment: Just read the whoe link about how to organize Layout. Then you will understand how to dynamically populate your desired layout and you can easily adopt it. Trust me it will help you a lot...

Comment: no, i only want editText. not all those views. i'm just givin u a sample. ah never minddddd... thanks for the help though.. (-___-)

Comment: still having a hard time understanding all of that. * i don't quite really understand English*. but thanks anyways...