# "How to concisely implement an editable table layout"

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-tablelayout

I am new to android and i am trying to get this specific layout for a project, but i want to know if there is a easier way to this, i have added the code of the .xml file and also an image of the layout that i desire. I also did a number of query search, but most of them end up with a solution that involves something known as MYSQL, and it really seemed intimidating for a beginner like me...

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ruturaj.myapplication.MainActivity">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText00"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.229" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText01"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.229" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText02"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="288dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.229" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText03"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="244dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.229" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText04"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.229" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText05"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.229" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText06"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="112dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.229" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText10"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.229" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText11"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.229" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText12"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="288dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.229" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText13"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="244dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.229" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText14"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.229" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText15"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.229" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText16"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="112dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.229" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText20"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.524" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText21"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.524" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText22"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="288dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.524" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText23"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="244dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.524" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText24"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.524" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText25"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.524" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText26"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="112dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.524" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText30"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.451" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText31"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.451" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText32"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="288dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.451" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText33"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="244dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.451" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText34"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.451" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText35"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.451" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText36"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="112dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.451" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText40"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.377" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText41"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.377" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText42"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="288dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.377" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText43"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="244dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.377" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText44"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.377" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText45"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.377" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText46"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="112dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.377" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText50"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.303" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText51"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.303" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText52"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="288dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.303" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText53"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="244dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.303" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText54"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.303" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText55"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.303" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText56"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="112dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.303" />
```

Comment: You should remove all but one of those table formatters. You should also rephrase your question - it's much more cleanly stated as something like "How to concisely implement an editable table layout".
You also mention research, but didn't link to any similar threads to indicate what you've tried...

Comment: You could consider a `GridLayout` or a `RecylerView` that uses a `GridLayoutManager` (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) to do this. I'd probably lean towards the latter. Each cell of the `RecyclerView` would be an `EditText` and the result would be very concise. You'll use `RecyclerView` all the time in Android development, so the investment in learning it will be time well spent.

Comment: @tehhowch thank you for suggesting the edit

Comment: @tehhowch is this feasible even if i wish to perform calculations on the numbers entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`
It may seem intimidating in the beginning, but is easier than it seems.
The idea is to create a list of views as a grid and give them separate functionality using the **Adapter**.

Here is a [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) where to start.

Good luck

Comment: is this feasible even if i wish to put numbers inside the views and perform calculations on them

Comment: you can keep a list of the inputs and update it when when a specific EditText is changed, then do the calculation getting all the numbers from the list

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear, as @tehhowch said, you should explain more what you want, and what you've tried.

However, you should try to use a GridView and populate it with EditText.
This is also explained here: [Create EditText in Gridlayout programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798199/create-edittext-in-gridlayout-programmatically-in-android][1]), although this example is not exactly what you want, you can easily change it for your desire, and even implement an adapter for handling gridview clicks and changes.

> XML:
>
> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:id="@+id/layout_main"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> android:orientation="vertical">
>
> <GridLayout
>     android:id="@+id/inputTasksLayout"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="0dp"
>     android:layout_weight="1"
>     android:columnCount="2"
>     android:rowCount="10">
>
>
> </GridLayout>
>
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/addnewTask"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:onClick="addView"
>     android:text="Add" />
> </LinearLayout>
> ```
>
> Activity:
>
> ```
> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
> int rowIndex = 1;
> int colIndex = 0;
> private GridLayout gridLayout;
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.inputTasksLayout);
>     gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
>
> }
>
> public void addView(View view) {
>     EditText editText = new EditText(this);
>     GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
>     param.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
>     param.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
>     param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(rowIndex);
>     param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(colIndex);
>     editText.setLayoutParams(param);
>     if (rowIndex == 1) {
>         editText.setId(R.id.task1);
>     }
>     if (rowIndex == 2) {
>         editText.setId(R.id.task2);
>     }
>
>     gridLayout.addView(editText);
>     rowIndex++;
>  }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can using GridView or RecyclerView to create the table, to do that you can start with simple GridView.

This guide: [Android GridView Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/127544/android-gridview-getting-started)